# php MySQL: problems with comparing timestamps in millis

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am getting really confused in the subject of Timestamps and their comparison.

What I want: I have a little chat application. Whenever the user is inside the chat, every 5 seconds an asynchronous request is sent to the server with the time in millis (from 5 seconds ago, the procedere is

1. Open chat
2. store actual time in millis
3. after 5 seconds send request with that value and store actual time in millis (REPEAT)

Now first of all, I am getting the actual millis in Javascript by doing so

```
var now = new Date();
lastChatChecked = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), 
                               now.getUTCMonth(), 
                               now.getUTCDate(),  
                               now.getUTCHours() + 1, 
                               now.getUTCMinutes(), 
                               now.getUTCSeconds(), 
                               now.getUTCMilliseconds());
lastChatChecked = lastChatChecked.getTime();
```

Note that I had to add a +1 at the hour field, since the timestamp was always an hour behind my time. Now, when sending this value to the server and doing something like this

```
SELECT commentContent, commentDate, userName  
    FROM chatComment c, User u 
    WHERE commentDate < ".$m." 
    AND c.userID = u.userID 
    AND teamID=".$tid." 
    ORDER BY c.commentDate DESC;
```

where $m are the millis. This does not work! I tested it manually by creating a millis value that is between some date values in the database, and no results are given back.

Now, should I convert the millis in php in a comparatible timestamp, or is there any other approach to do this? I saw this approach in an so-question

```
WHERE commentDate < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 SECONDS)
```

but still no results.

**scheme**

(from head, I do not have the schemes right here)

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    userID      INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    userName    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    userPW      VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (userID),
    UNIQUE (userName)
)ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE(
    commentID       INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    userID          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    teamID          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    commentContent  VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    commentDate     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (commentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES User (userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (teamID) REFERENCES Team (teamID)
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

**php**

```
function getNewestMessages($m){
    mysql_query ('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT teamID FROM Team WHERE teamName='".$_SESSION['tn']."';");
    $temp = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $temp[] = $row;
    }
    $tid = $temp[0]['teamID'];

    $query = "SELECT commentContent, commentDate, userName  from chatComment c, User u WHERE commentDate < ".$m." AND c.userID = u.userID AND teamID=".$tid." ORDER BY c.commentDate DESC;";
    $res2 = mysql_query($query);
    $temp2 = array();

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
        $temp2[] = $row2;
    }

    echo json_encode($temp2);
}
```

some **results** of `SELECT commentDate FROM chatComment;`

```
2014-02-06 21:50:08  
2014-02-06 21:50:11  
2014-02-06 21:53:11  
2014-02-06 21:54:12  
2014-02-06 21:54:17  
2014-02-06 21:56:16
```

some **results** when editing to

```
echo json_encode($m)

"1391792194985"  
"1391792198943"  
"1391792203927"  


echo json_encode(round($m/1000))

1391792144  
1391792149  
1391792154  
1391792159
```

(It seems that the Javascript function date.getTime() does return millis...)

Comment: I really hope you're [escaping your SQL statements correctly](http://bobby-tables.com/) because string concatenation is usually a sign you're not.

Comment: Where and what is the value $m? do you have single quotes around your values?

Comment: @tadman I am checking this serverside.

Comment: @DamienBlack I already wrote in my question that $m are the millis. Since it is a numerical value, I do not put it into quotes. Does this the trick?

Comment: What database interface are you using here? How do you execute the query?

Comment: Well, I'm just guessing here because you didn't give us your schema, but commentDate looks like a date, and a value in 'millis' (like what? the millis since the last 5 seconds, like 5000?) is not a date. So, I feel like this isn't going to work the way you want it to.

Comment: @DamienBlack see updatet question. That's what I ask, should I convert the millis into a date in php to compare? the millis represent a date 5 seconds ago, and it's double checked that the value is correct. I will also add the php function

Comment: how does a value in millis represent a date from 5 seconds ago? why don't you show us how $m is calculated or what the value in it might be. This is the key and you keep leaving it out.

Comment: The millis are calculated in Javascript (like explained above ;) ). Your question does not make sense! A timestamp is ALWAYS represented in millis, so why should I not be able to represent a date in millis. I get the actual millis, wait 5 seconds and POFF, a date from five seconds agp

Comment: Timestamps are in seconds, not millis.

Comment: So we got my problem! I knew it would be something in basic understanding of Timestamps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it sounds like your $m value is in milliseconds. Now I'm not sure if that means milliseconds from the epoch, like a millisecond timestamp, but if so, you need to translate it to seconds. MySQL timestamps are in seconds.

```
SELECT commentContent, commentDate, userName  
FROM chatComment c, User u 
WHERE commentDate < ".$m/1000." 
AND c.userID = u.userID 
AND teamID=".$tid." 
ORDER BY c.commentDate DESC;
```

In addition, your '<' sign seems backwards. If you want all the entries *after* the time you need

```
commentDate > ".$m/1000."
```

Finally, it looks like your schema is wrong and commentDate is not a timestamp. It is actually a 'datetime', which is different. So you need to convert the timestamp to a datetime:

```
 commentDate > FROM_UNIXTIME($m/1000)
```

Comment: Ok, since I did not know that a timestamp is in seconds, I even did not know that my $m is already in seconds! Which throws my question back to the beginning... I generated a seconds value from this morning and queried the database with your query, still no results.

Comment: I see you getting milliseconds in your code. Are you saying $m is calculated elsewhere?

Comment: In Javascript. I create a Timestamp and call getTime(), which gives me seconds (if I take this value and put it in a timestamp generator, everything is ok). There are no millis at all in the code, it is only named as millis since I thought they were millis. Now you should see everything in the question, and it is also guaranteed that there are entries in the db which vary in time

Comment: Are you trying to get the comments that have happened in the last 5 seconds?

Comment: Almost: the function is used mainly for that yes! But I want to use it too to load all comments since the last logout for example.

Comment: Ok, your < is backwards then.

Comment: If I revert it, all data is selected. I tried it with various generated 'timestamps' in seconds, but it's always the same. Is there a problem with the comparison itself?

Comment: Can you catch you $m value and print it? Let me know what the value is. It sounds like it is too low to represent a proper timestamp. Can you also pull out some of the values in commentDate? SELECT commentDate from chatComment

Comment: I mean, in the end I need a function that returns me al rows after a certain date. Should I change my whole approach?

Comment: updated my answer, commentDate is a 'datetime', not a timestamp.

Comment: ok I see. Can I ask why does the engine produces a datetime, if I declare TIMESTAMP in the CREATE TABLE query?